# The 'polarization' term in the first order variational principle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism

Going from the Lagrangian to the Hamiltonian formalism, the action can be rewritten as
$$ S= \int L = \int p\mathrm d q - H\mathrm dt\,,$$
where $(p,q)$ are the phase space variables and $H$ is the Hamiltonian.

Now, I have heard that the first term $p\mathrm d q$ is sometimes referred to as a 'polarization term'. Why is that?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Heard where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name *polarization term* is probably derived from the choice of [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization#Polarization) in geometric quantization. $$\vartheta~=~p_i\mathrm {d} q^i$$ is sometimes called the *symplectic potential 1-form,* because $$\omega~=~\mathrm {d}\vartheta~=~\mathrm {d}p_i\wedge \mathrm {d} q^i$$ is the *symplectic 2-form.*